# Filters do not apply

Tags: symfony, filter, api-platform.com

I have filters, but they do not apply to data

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter; 

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\HostRepository")
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     routePrefix="/profile"
 * )
 *
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"id": "exact"})
 *
 */
class Host
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    .....
```

I send such a request
http://localhost/api/profile/hosts?id=1

All answers are returned to me (including id = 1)
Same result with 'name' and other parameters

What could be the problem?

Comment: why do you even want filter on id field? simple `http://localhost/api/profile/hosts/1` should make the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not indicated in the documentation. But the filter will not work until you specify in the file api_platform.yaml

```
framework:
    serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
```

As correctly noted in the comments, this is mentioned in the documentation in the configuration section:
api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization#configuration

Comment: Actually it is mentioned in documentation. https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization#configuration